# JdbcTestUtils and transaction context tests

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-test

I have this problem that is causing me not to use `JdbcTestUtils` when running tests with a Transactional context.

If I wrap my test with `@Transactional` annotation and use a `JdbcTemplate/DataSource` it looks like the transactions used in the production code and by the JdbcTestUtils are not the same, so if I query the db in the `then` section the assertion fails.

This is a pseudo test:

```
@SpringBootTest
class TestClass {

  @Autowired
  private WebApplicationContext context;

  @BeforeEach
  void setup() {
    RestAssuredMockMvc.webAppContextSetup(context, springSecurity());
  }

  @Test
  @Transactional
  @DisplayName("test1")
  void test1(@Autowired DataSource dataSource) {
    //given
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
    assertThat(countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "some_tbl")).isEqualTo(1);

    //when
    // Execute app code here that adds a record to some_tbl

    //then
    assertThat(countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "some_tbl")).isEqualTo(2); //<- Assertion fails. 
  }
```

As a workaround, I need to use Spring contexted test repositories to retrieve data in the test, but that feels like a bad idea, and I need to maintain these repositories.

Below you will find a simple spring-boot project to show the issue.
https://github.com/Marek00Malik/JdbcTestUtils-sample

Comment: can you add the actual app code you are testing here? Also shouldn't the assertion be two records in the table? You start with one and add one during the test?

Comment: You're right, it should be 2 as stated in the description. The production code is just a simple method that stores a single new record. I'm accessing it using rest api, but that should not be any different. The feature works as expected, but I need to test the addition differently (not by JdbcTestUtils) because I want to have the change rollback after the test is finished. If you need a sample repo I can create one, but I don't see any point in it. This is not the first time I have this problem.

Comment: still, it would be great to see what a _simple method_ is. So your basic problem is that you can't prepare test data with `JdbcTemplate` for a test or is it different?

Comment: https://github.com/Marek00Malik/JdbcTestUtils-sample
Example of the issue at hand. One test is working if I will query the db before the JdbcTestUtil.

Comment: Just a note, I'm aware of the use of saveAndFlush, but this solution adds additional performance as you need to flush the jpa context to the disk.  So if it's possible to use the traditional save method this would be recommended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cloned your project and could verify the failing test on my machine.

The reason for your test failure within the assertion of the test `failingTestStoringNewObject`:

```
assertThat(countRowsInTable(jdbcTemplate, "sample_table")).isEqualTo(1);
```

is that the `EntityManger` of JPA (the Spring Data JPA repositories use this under the hood) follows a write-behind strategy and keeps changes to JPA entities in its first-level cache (in-memory). Flushing the changes to the database does not always happen when your code executes `.save()` or any other database operation using the `EntityManager`.

The `EntityManger` tries to postpone flushing and therefore synchronizing its first-level cache with the database as late as possible. There is a lot to read about this and I can recommend [Vlad Mihalcea's guide on this](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpahibernate-flush-strategies/).

In your case, as you annotate your test with `@Transactional`, your changes will be rolled back after the test and therefore never committed to the database. You can see this in the log of the test:

```
2020-07-20 09:59:57.754  INFO 12648 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.c.transaction.TransactionContext   : Rolled back transaction for test: [DefaultTestContext@2b8ade2d testClass = SimpleObjectResourceHttpTest, testInstance = pl.code.house.example.jdbc.template.jdbctemplatetest.SimpleObjectResourceHttpTest@
```

For more visualization on this, you can also enable SQL logging for your tests with

```
spring:
  jpa:
    show-sql: on
```

You'll see that there is actually no `INSERT` statement executed, but a call to fetch the primary key of your entity.

If you *temporarily* use `repository.saveAndFlush(newObj).toDto();` inside your `SimpleObjectFacade`, you'll see that it works.

I would use the `SimpleObjectRepository` for your integration test and use the `.count()` method of it. In this case, the underlying `EntityManager` recognizes a call to the same table and will flush its current changes before that and you'll get your expected result. Because if you use the `JdbcTemplate` there is no interaction with the `EntityManager` and therefore the `EntityManager` does not flush it changes as you go directly to the database with a `SELECT COUNT(0) ...`.

**UPDATE**: If you don't want to make any adjustments and still use the `JdbcTemplate` in conjunction with Hibernate and the `JpaRepositories`, you *could* set the following flush mode for your tests only:

```
spring.jpa.properties.org.hibernate.flushMode=ALWAYS
```

This ensures to always flush the persistence context

Comment: Thank you Rieckpil. This is something that I'm already aware, I'm currently using a TestImplementation of my production repository, so I can use it in other places in my test code. As mentioned, this is a workaround and I would much like not to do it as sometimes I need to write JPA queries that are specific to the test case and not to the repo in general.

Comment: Also, a note about JdbcTemplate which is used by JdbcTestUtil:
"
A JdbcTemplate, for executing SQL statements to query the database. You can use such queries to confirm database state both before and after execution of database-related application code, and Spring ensures that such queries run in the scope of the same transaction as the application code. When used in conjunction with an ORM tool, be sure to avoid false positives.
"
This is why I was hoping JdbcTestUtil would execute in the same transaction as the test code.

Comment: The last sentence of your quote outlines the issue _When used in conjunction with an ORM tool, be sure to avoid false positives._. I've updated my answer with a workaround.

Comment: Yeap, that probably would be the cause of it. It's still weird, I would imagine that for testing Spring is running the @Transactional tests in single test session configuration, this way when you use JdbcTestUtil you would get the same transaction. But maybe it's more "generic" this way. Who knows. Thank Rieckpill for help!